# GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object A with class A to class A

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, dcm4che

I've a problem with a grails 3 application using dcm4che3 DICOM toolkit.

First of all the code is running and doing what it is supposed to do. But after a while it's not working anymore and I receive a GroovyCastException.

This is the Exception message I don't really understand:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'org.dcm4che3.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader@2e5177d0' with class 'org.dcm4che3.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader' to class 'org.dcm4che3.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader'
```

In my code it looks like this:

```
Iterator<ImageReader> iter    = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
DicomImageReader dReader      = (DicomImageReader) iter.next();
```

There is a image reader registered for DICOM. And it is returned and working well. But after a while it seems to brake somehow.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you

grailsfan

Comment: are you running in `development` mode?

Comment: No, it's a war file running in tomcat 8.5 in production mode

Comment: try using `def reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM").find{ DicomImageReader.isAssignableFrom it.getClass() }`. Looks like the registry is chainging with time and you should not alway pick the 1st object from there

Comment: Thx, I will try it